# Return false from Promise: should it resolve(false) or reject()?

Tags: error-handling, promise

I am making a request to a server via HTTP, to see if a user with a specific email exists.

```js
function userExists(id) {
    return makeHttpRequestToServer(id)
        .then((response) => {
            if (response === 200) {
                // User exists in the database
            } else if (response === 404) {
                // User does not exist in the database
            }
        });
}
```

I am unsure how I should handle the `resolve`/`reject` calls:

- Should I `resolve()` when the user is found in the database, and `reject()` when the user is not found in the database?
- Should I `resolve(true)` when the user is found in the database, and `accept(false)` when the user is not found in the database?

Answer (score 9):

You should use `resolve` to return any non-error response, and `reject` only for errors and exceptions.

Searching for a specific entry in a database that does not contain the entry is not necessarily an error, so you should `resolve(false)`.

```js
function userExists(id) {
    return makeHttpRequestToServer(id)
        .then((response) => {
            if (response === 200) {
                // User exists in the database
                resolve(true);
            } else if (response === 404) {
                // User does not exist in the database
                resolve(false);
            } else {
                // Something bad happened
                reject(new Error("An error occurred"));
            }
        });
}
```

This makes it easier to differentiate between returning `false`, and having an error occur.

When handling callbacks, it is conventional to preserve the first returned argument for error responses, and the remaining arguments for returned values.

```js
function userExists(id, callback) {
    makeHttpRequestToServer(id)
        .then((response) => {
            if (response === 200) {
                // User exists in the database
                callback(undefined, true);
            } else if (response === 404) {
                // User does not exist in the database
                callback(undefined, false);
            } else {
                // Something bad happened
                callback(new Error(response));
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: In this particular example, you don't need the `Promise` wrapper because it seems `makeHttpRequest` already returns a Promise.  Maybe, show an api that has a callback instead?

Comment: @DavinTryon You're absolutely right, the Promise wrapper was redundant. I've removed it, and added a small part about callbacks.

Comment: @DavinTryon Ok, I've just realised, the Promise wrapper is not redundant, because I need it so I can have `resolve` and `reject` functions.