# Is returning true/false for a function as indicator for success/failure considered a good standard in JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, standards, web-standards

Im trying to understand something regarding JS standards:

When writing an async function or any function that returns any kind of promise I need to assume that the user of this function will want to catch the rejection and not to expect a boolean value in the resolve:

Good:

```
doSomething = async () => {
  ...
  if (failed)
     reject(error)
  
  resolve("yay")
}

try {
  await doSomething()
  console.log("yay worked")
}
catch (error){
}
```

Bad:

```
  doSomething = async () => {
  ...
  if (failed)
     resolve(false)
  
  resolve(true)
}

didWork = await doSomething()
if (didWork){
  console.log("yay")
else { 
}
```

But my question is regarding non-async functions, is returning true/false as indicator as a success/failure considered a bad habit? any other good way to indicate success/failure?
Also, tell me if my assumption above above good habits regarding promises is right in your eyes.

Thank you!

Comment: About the async way, I saw that in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48811364/return-false-from-promise-should-it-resolvefalse-or-reject#:~:text=You%20should%20use%20resolve%20to,you%20should%20resolve(false)%20.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with returning a boolean. What does your non-async function do?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea. You may want to return actual data if you call `findLowestNumber(array)` you'd expect a number, not a boolean. The usual way to handle problems is either deal with them and return some normalised value (e.g., `-Infinity` or `null` could be an appropriate value from `findLowestNumber`). The other way is to throw an exception. I don't see a value in going halfway.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same for async and non-async functions really:

- `true`/`false` can be a legitimate answer to the posed question
- an exception/promise rejection is a sign of a serious failure

For example, if the purpose of your function is to determine whether a string is numeric, the return values `true` and `false` have an obvious meaning. However, if you're passing in an object, which isn't a string to begin with, an *exception* is appropriate since the answer to the question "is this string numeric" for an object is ["mu"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(negative)#%22Unasking%22_the_question) ‍♂️.

For an async function the same holds true: if it takes a network request to get a `true`/`false` answer for some question, then resolving the promise with `true`/`false` is entirely cromulent; e.g. if you're checking with the server whether an entered user name is still available, "yes" and "no" are valid answers. If the network request itself fails however, that would be an *exceptional failure*, a "mu", which you need to signal by rejecting the entire promise.

A promise rejection is just an *asynchronous exception*; with the `await` syntax it is even handled the same as a synchronous exception. An exception is used for *exceptional events*, when a normal answer cannot be provided due to circumstances beyond the normal [happy path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_path).

Comment: In your first example you'd best not throw an exception unless the object can't be converted to a string with its own toString() method. To do that just cast the argument to a string and it will throw on its own if it can't convert.